# Will deleting a menu option delete the page that it links to?

Tags: menu, menu-item

I have inherited our Bowling centre's website from my previous manager and have found quite a mess of various menus which we do not need any more.

These menus refer to the annual tournament we organise and there are hundreds of these referring to previous years and it requires a lot of scrolling and searching until I find the correct menu item I require.

So I have decided to streamline the tournament menus and create 1 set which will be used each year and I will just amend the page to which each particular menu item is linked.

I would like to know whether deleting these extra menus which I do not require anymore would delete the page they are linked to also?

[image: Example of multiple menus]

[image: Example of multiple menu items]

I have searched through the questions here and have not been able to find any previous posts that relate to my issue.

Comment: Welcome Eden.  Please take our [tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting menus or menu items will not affect the content (eg a k2 item) to which the menu item is assigned.

Once a menu item is deleted the url of that menu item will no longer work. Menu items are for making and organising urls and they also hold the itemid to which modules are assigned.

Comment: Thank you for the concise reply.